# Dynamic object filter

Tags: python, django

I have a filter query which varies depending on the search criteria,

Sometimes it is:

```
Thing.object.filter(name__startswith=word).distinct('id')
```

and sometimes:

```
Thing.object.filter(city__startswith=word)
```

So everything after `.filter(` can change. Is there a way to set this dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 'city' and 'name' are values of a criteria selector, you can do something like this:

```
queryset = Thing.object.filter(**{'%s__startswith' % criteria: word})

if criteria_requires_distinct:
    queryset = queryset.distinct()
```

Comment: this is a nice approach, i like it. so after `distinct()` i will touch db twice, right?

Comment: No, just once you fetch the result

Comment: what is ``fetch result`` in code? :(. when i do `return render_to_response("index.html",queryset,context_instance=RequestContext(request))` ?

Comment: result would be once you iterate through the queryset. It will touch the db once perform for example "for thing in queryset:" doesn't metter in the view or in the template

Answer (score 3):

The arguments to `.filter()`, yes. Just create a dictionary.

```
D = {'city__startswith': word}
things = Thing.object.filter(**D)
```

The call to `.distinct()`, no. You will need to special case that.

Comment: can i do that `distinct()` part with Q objects?

Comment: Uh, no. You do it with a method call.

Comment: i have a dic of lookups as you said `D`. but some of them needs `distinct`, can i do a keylookup and set distinct part and THEN make a query to db?

Comment: No query is performed until you request the results.

Comment: what do you mean with untill i request the results? what i try and cannot do now is: 
``if name__startswith in D: Thing.object.filter(name__startswith=word).distinct('id')``, this will query only for name. but i want for all criterias